# css has() selector weirdness (chrome)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Recently, I had a case where the has() selector seemed to provide the answer to a problem. And I found that it isn't. And not because FireFox doesn't support it. (Although that is a problem too.)

To show this I made a codepen [lookahead selector is weird](https://codepen.io/studentfrank/pen/YzLbgLq)
The bit with class v1 is the first solution I came up with. And I have no idea why it doesn't work.

When I saw v1 didn't work, I came up with the alternative with class v2. That also didn't work. But I could at least understand why.

Considering that the halves that did work cover all that I need, I made the one with class v3.

Intrigued by v1 not working, I also made v1a,to see if I could figure out which part of the selection doesn't do what I think it does.

And that shows just how weird has() is. Adding the rule for the background of the table flipped the does/doesn't work on the rules.

Also, by accident, I ended up wildly moving across the elements of the table of v1. And at some moment...both rules started working. For v1a, the same. If you want to see this, just make circles on the v1 table hitting all the tds until you see both spans on the right responding.

I tried with both Chrome and Edge. FireFox simply doesn't support it. And I don't happen to have Safari handy to try it on.

Can anyone give an explanation so I understand what is going on? Preferably with pointers to getting something that works in a way that makes a bit more sense.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.v1a:has(td .span1:hover) {
  background-color: green;
}

.v1:has(td .span3:hover) tr td .span2, /* Ok  */
.v1:has(td .span1:hover) tr td .span4 { /* NOk. Why? */
  background-color: red;
}

.v2 tr:has(td .span3:hover)~tr td .span2, /* NOk, but I know why. */
.v2 tr:has(td .span1:hover)~tr td .span4 { /* Ok  */
  background-color: red;
}

.v3:has(td .span3:hover) tr td .span2, /* Ok  */
.v3 tr:has(td .span1:hover)~tr td .span4 { /* Ok  */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="v1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span1">1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span2">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span3">3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span4">4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="v1 v1a">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span1">1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span2">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span3">3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span4">4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="v2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span1">1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span2">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span3">3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span4">4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="v3">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span1">1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span2">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="span3">3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="span4">4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works as expected for me in Chrome. When I hover span1, span4 turns red.

Comment: if you use the selector alone it works `.v1:has(td .span1:hover) tr td .span4 { 
  background-color: red;
}`

Comment: Just that v1-span1 does work for me too. So, there isn't really anything wrong with the selector itself. It's really the interaction with the v1-span3 that makes it go wrong. I tried splitting up the rules. (So 1 for v1-span1 and 1 for v1-span3 separately) that behaves like the v1 in the codepen.

Comment: @Gerard Weird. What version of Chrome? I have automatic updates on. It says version 106.0.5249.119. Edge is also a 106.0.

Comment: Using Microsoft Edge Version 108.0.1445.0 (Official build) canary (64-bit) and Chrome Version 109.0.5367.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Comment: Looks like you have newer versions. But mine both say they are up to date on106. I guess I will just have to be patient for the updates...

Comment: I just got 107. The problem persists. I guess it's waiting for 108 to get pushed.

Comment: Finally got 108. And it's working as expected now. Edge still at 107, though. Case closed, I think.

Comment: And Edge is at 108 too. It's working.